# Question on big o proofs

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the following question:

Is the following statement true or false?

**All logs to base 2**

log2n is a member of O(log(n))

My attempt:

- log2n - clogn <= 0
- log2 + logn - clogn <= 0
- 1 + logn(1-c) <= 0

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but I have to find values for n (variable) and c (constant) which either prove or disprove this...

Generally this seems to be true:

Choose

```
n0 = 2, c = 3 -> TRUE 
n1 = 3, c = 3 -> TRUE 
n2 = 4, c = 3 -> TRUE
```

Therefore, the statement seems true, logn increases as n does. But there are also values for which the above statement will never hold:

e.g.

Choose c = 1 evaluates to greater than zero regardless of the increasing value of n.

So I am confused as to whether this is true or false....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the fact that the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms of the factors:

`log(2n) = log(2)+log(n) = O(log(n))`

Comment: Ok that does tell me it's true. Unfortunately I have to prove it using the method above. I am just confused to why certain values evaluate to false.

Comment: @user559142: All you have to do is show that the condition is satisfied for *one* value of `c` (for all sufficiently large `n`). You don't have to prove (and it's generally not the case) that the condition holds for *every* `c`.